# Error while installing gbm in R on redhat

Tags: r, redhat, gbm

I want to install gbm in R so using the command `install.packages("gbm")` but getting the error message:

```
Error : package 'parallel' could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gbm’
```

My system is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.2 (Santiago)`. Any solution?

**EDIT:**

When I try to install "parallel" using `install.packages("parallel")` I get the following warning:

```
Warning in install.packages("parallel") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/home/abhay/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.10'
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘parallel’ is not available
```

What library should I specify?